# my function doesn't get called

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code, which is correct in my eyes:

```
<button onclick="clear()" class="button button-positive btn">Delete Local Storage</button>
```

And this function:

```
function clear() {
  localStorage.clear();
  console.log("Hello")
}
```

The function doesn't get called and the log as well.

The files are linked correctly.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Looks like: `console.log("Hello")` missing a `;`

Comment: make sure that the js part is loaded properly

Comment: @daalbert - the "missing" semicolon isn't a syntax error and won't prevent the code from working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `clear` is reserved keyword, please do use another function name like `clearLog()` instead of `clear()`.

```js
function clearLog() {
   localStorage.clear();
   console.log("Hello")
}
```

```html
<button onClick="clearLog()" class="button button-positive btn">Delete Local Storage</button>
```

**Update**

As **Arun** said, `clear` is reserved with same scope `document.clear()`

Comment: `clear` is a perfectly valid method name, - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9yb7g1e3/1/ - the problem here is there is another method with that name in the given scope

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the inline event handler scope, clear refers to [document.clear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear) method.

You can just rename the method to get it called

```js
function clearMe() {
  localStorage.clear();
  console.log("Hello")
}
```

```html
<button onclick="console.log(clear);clearMe()" class="button button-positive btn">Delete Local Storage</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use clear as function name. It seems that the called function is 
 Invoking [`document.clear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear)

```js
function clearStorage() {
  localStorage.clear();
  console.log("Hello");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clearStorage()" class="button button-positive btn">Delete Local Storage</button>
```

> NOTE:Try not to use global namespace or function

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    <button onclick="javascript:Clear()" class="button button-positive btn">Delete Local Storage</button>
   <script>
    function Clear() {
      console.log("before localstorage clear");
    try{      
      localStorage.clear();
   }
     catch(err){
     console.log("err in clearing function "+err);
}
      console.log("Hello");
    }
    </script>
```

Error may arised due to localstorage.clear() function

Comment: Thanks, but why do i have to do this?

Comment: sometimes is script function not known if it defined in some other part.

Comment: No, please *don't* add `javascript:` in an inline html attribute event handler. You don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to rename your function  beacuse `clear` is reserved keyword

```
    function clr() {
      localStorage.clear();
      console.log("Hello")
    }
```

this is HTML

```
<button onclick="clr()" class="button button-positive btn">Delete Local Storage</button>
```